# Azure DevOps Build Xamarin.Android 9.4.1.0 as target in hosted macOS image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an Application written with Xamarin and a buildpipline on Azure Devops. This builds fine when I built it locally with Xamarin.Android 9.4.1.0. However, I would like to update to SDK 9.4.1.0 since the default version in the mac agent is 9.0.0-20.

I'm facing an issue which was discussed and had a solution here.
https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/1320

The solution is to change the Xamarin.Android sdk from 9.0 to 9.2(higher).

Comment: So, you have resolved your question? And you want to share the solution here? If yes, I suggest that separate your question and answer, so it could help other community members to check the answer.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT In the given link it says changing the sdk version will solve this. So my question here is how to change the SDK. Still I'm looking for answer.

Comment: Which agent you are using? Is `macOS-10.13` or `macOS-10.14`? AFAIK, the version `9.4.1.0` of that SDK installed in those agent. https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/macos/macos-10.13-Readme.md#xamarinandroid-sdk.

Comment: `macOS-10.14` and the version `9.4.1.0` is installed in it.

Comment: So, you question is that when you build project with `Xamarin.Android`, it used the old version  `9.0.0-20` not the `9.4.1.0` and you want to change the default version to `9.4.1.0`? Am I right?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Correct.

Comment: To change the default SDK version, you can try to manually select a Xamarin SDK version to use on the Hosted macOS agent, before your Xamarin build task, execute this command line as part of your build, replacing the Mono version number 5.4.1 as needed and Choose the Mono version that is associated with the Xamarin SDK version that you need. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&viewFallbackFrom=azdevops#how-can-i-manually-select-versions-of-tools-on-the-hosted-macos-agent. Please check if this help.